# String Incorrectly Splitting

Tags: java, split

I'm attempting to print out elements of a string using split("#"), with # being the character separating the elements. My code is below (movies is the string being printed):

```
String[] tokens = movies.split("#");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    System.out.println(tokens[i]); 
}
```

Here's the contents of movies:

```
1 Skyfall#2 The Impossible#
```

Here's what's being printed:

```
1 Skyfall
2 The Impossible
2
```

If I modify the code above so it loops (tokens.length - 1) times instead of tokens.length, this is printed:

```
1 Skyfall
2
```

Here's the method that makes the string stored in movies. This uses a LinkedList. lineNumbers is true in this case. numItems is the amount of Listnode< String> (aka a movie) in the LinkedList.

```
String list = "";
int pos = 0;
ListNode node = head;
if (numItems == 0){
    return "Empty";
}
while (pos < numItems){
    if (lineNumbers){
        list += (pos + 1) + " ";
    }
    list += node.getData() + "#";  
    pos++;
    if (pos < numItems){
        node = node.getNext();
    }
}  
return list;
```

I cannot figure out why it's printing that extra number. Can anyone help?

Comment: Print the length of tokens to get the answser.

Comment: What you think the contents of Movies is isn't what is being run.  The `split` works fine, and it splits it as you would expect it to.

Comment: I used your code and it gave me correct output.

Comment: i used the code...
it's gives correct answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this code

```
 list += (pos + 1) + " ";
```

is getting executed twice. Please check your condition for linenumbers.that is true when it should be false.

and after the statment pos++ is executed the second condition

```
if (pos < numItems){
```

is not satisfied and it breaks.

so ultimately you have

1 Skyfall#2 The Impossible#2#

Answer (score 1):

You havent posted your full code so its difficult to be accurate. But your split is fine.

I bet the problem is because a mismatch between `lineNumbers` and `pos`